# How to diagnose weird race-condition-bug?

Tags: c++, race-condition, vxworks

The bug we are tracking occurs within a specific VxWorks-based embedded environment (the vendor modified stuff to an unknown extend and provides an abstraction layer of much of the VxWorks-stuff). We have two tasks running at different priorities, executing roughly every 100ms. The task with the higher priority simply counts adds counts up an integer (just so it does anything), while the task with the lower priority creates a string, like this:

```
std::string text("Some text");
```

Note that there is no shared state between these task whatsoever. They both operate exclusively on automatic local variables.

On each run, each task does this a hundred times, so that the probability of the race-condition occurring is higher. The application runs fine for a couple of minutes, and then the CPU-load shots from 5% to 100% and stays there. The entire time appears to be used by the task that created the string. So far we have not been able to reproduce the behavior without using `std::string`.

We are using GCC 4.1.2 and running on VxWorks 5.5. The program is run on a Pentium III.

I have tried analyzing what happens there, but I cannot enter any of the `string`-methods with a debugger, and adding print-statements into basic-string does not seem to work (this was the background for [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230149/)). My suspicion is that something in there corrupts the stack resulting in a power-loop. My question is, is there any know error in older VxWorks-versions that could explain this? If not, do you have any further suggestions how to diagnose this? I can get the disassembly and stack-dumps, but I have no experience in interpreting either. Can anyone [provide some pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/)?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, vxWorks provides thread specific memory locations (or possibly just one location).  This feature lets you specify a memory location that will be automatically shadowed by task switches so that whenever a thread writes on it the value is preserved across task switches.  It's sort of like an additional register save/restore.

GCC uses one of those thread-specific memory locations to track the exception stack.  Even if you don't otherwise use exceptions there are some situations (particularly `new`, such as the `std::string` constructor might invoke) which implicitly create `try/catch` like environments which manipulate this stack.  On a much older version of gcc I saw that go haywire in code that nominally did not use any exception handling.

In that case the solution was to compile with `-fno-exceptions` to eliminate all of that behavior, after which the problem went away.

Comment: Compiling with `-fno-exceptions` did not help. I also could not reproduce the bug by manually creating a `try/catch` environment and allocating/deallocating memory using `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see a weird race-condition in a VxWorks system with unexplainable behavior, my first thought is always "VX_FP_TASK strikes again!" The first thing you should check is whether your threads are being created with the VX_FP_TASK flag in taskSpawn.

The documentation says something like "It is deadly to execute any floating-point operations in a task spawned without VX_FP_TASK option, and very difficult to find." Now, you may think that you're not using FP registers at all, but C++ uses them for some optimizations, and MMX operations (like you may be using for your add there) do require those registers to be preserved.